# Como faço para Autodetect do firefox com Selenium webdriver em c# (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Preciso selecionar o `Autodetect` do profile do Firefox antes de rodar meu `script`, pois nas configurações de rede do browser está vindo como usar configurações do sistema. Dessa forma não consigo nem abrir o sistema.

Consegui fazer com `java`, mas aqui tem, coisas que já conhecemos, exigências da empresa para fazer com `c#` no `Visual Studio`.

Segue Código feito em Selenium WEBDriver Java:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.Proxy;
import org.openqa.selenium.Proxy.ProxyType;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class TestesdeLayoutdeTelaSimulacaoEscolhadePlanoPortal {

      private static ArrayList<String> urlList = new ArrayList<String>();

       @BeforeClass
       public static void setup() {

           urlList.add("http://satktsao02web01:8085/front-sales/#/simulation");
       }

 @Test
       public void passTraffixThroughProxyTest() {
 DesiredCapabilities capability = new DesiredCapabilities();
           addProxyCapabilities(capability);

           for (@SuppressWarnings("unused") String url : urlList){
               WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capability);
               driver.get("http://satktsao02web01:8085/front-sales/#/simulation");
               driver.manage().window().maximize();
                  public static DesiredCapabilities addProxyCapabilities(DesiredCapabilities capability) {
           Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
           **proxy.setProxyType(ProxyType.AUTODETECT);**

           capability.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
           capability.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
           return capability;
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: DÊ mais informações, mostre como fez em Java.

Comment: **proxy.setProxyType(ProxyType.AUTODETECT);** ---> Desconsiderar **

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido, segue para `C#`:

```
var ff = new FirefoxProfile();
ff.SetPreference("network.proxy.type", (int)ProxyKind.AutoDetect);
var driver = new FirefoxDriver(ff);
```